# Cypress Vue Component Test Runner - testing a button click has emitted an event

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I'm having trouble working out how to do a simple test of a Vue component (using the Cypress Component Test Runner) to see if a button click results in an event being emitted

```js
// MyButton.vue component
    <template>
      <Button
        data-testid="button"
        label="Click Button"
        @click="clickButton()"
      />
    </template>
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import { defineEmits } from "vue";
    const emit = defineEmits(["clickButtonEvent"]);
    
    function clickButton() {
      emit("clickButtonEvent");
    }
    </script>
```

```js
// MyButton.spec.ts
    it.only("should emit an even when clicked", () => {
      const clickButtonSpy = cy.spy().as("clickButtonEvent");
    
      mount(FulfilButton, {
        global: {
          components: {
            Button,
          },
        },
      })
      .get('[data-testid="button"]')
      .click();
    
      cy.get("@clickButtonEvent").should("have.been.called");
    });
```

This doesn't work - in the console I see

```
mount
get
-click
```

but then this:

```
expect clickButtonEvent to have been called at least once, but it was never called
```

So I guess I am not hooking up this `cy.spy` correctly - presumably because I am not doing it as part of the mount?  What do I need to do?  The button itself is a PrimeVue button component but I'm pretty sure that should not stop me doing this test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you are not hooking the spy at all.

The Cypress `mount` command has the same interface as `vue-test-utils` `mount` (it is using `vue-test-utils` under the hood)

In `vue-test-utils` v1 (for Vue 2) you can use [listeners](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#listeners) mount option to attach the spy as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052977/381282)

But since you are using Vue 3 and in turn [vue-test-utils v2](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/) where `listeners` mount option [was removed](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils-next/issues/321#issuecomment-770102939), probably your best option to use recommended API of the wrapper - [emitted](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#emitted)

This example is taken from the [recent talk of Jessica Sachs](https://youtu.be/7S5cbY8iYLk?t=888) (Cypress team member) ([repo](https://github.com/JessicaSachs/cypress-loves-vite/blob/develop/src/components/PerksModal.cy.js)) where she does something like this:

```js
mount(FulfilButton, {
  global: {
    components: {
      Button,
    },
  },
})
.get('[data-testid="button"]')
.click()
.vue()
.then((wrapper) => {
  expect(wrapper.emitted('clickButtonEvent')).to.have.length(1)
})
```

**Note** that `vue()` is not a build-in Cypress command. In this demo/repo it was added by Jessica in the [support file](https://github.com/JessicaSachs/cypress-loves-vite/blob/develop/cypress/support/index.js)

```js
// ./cypress/support/index.js

Cypress.Commands.add('vue', () => {
  return cy.wrap(Cypress.vueWrapper)
})
```

You can do something very similar without introducing any helper ([example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/npm/vue/cypress/component/button/button-counter-spec.js))

```js
it('emits "increment" event on click', () => {
    cy.get('button')
    .click()
    .click()
    .then(() => {
      cy.wrap(Cypress.vueWrapper.emitted()).should('have.property', 'increment')
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thanks - actually I watched the same talk and I reached out to Jessica about this vue() command yesterday because that does not work for me (I get "property vue does not exist on type Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>"- she said the Vue command was "not installed by default" and I'm not entirely sure what that means - do you?  This is exactly the way I wanted to do this test but without the Vue command in there I can't

Comment: sorry - not "added by default" was what she said

Comment: Thank you!  cy.wrap(Cypress.vueWrapper.emitted()).should('have.property' seems to work

Comment: I had the same issue with Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>. Types are not working but test pass.
@RichardShergold Did you find out a working solution ?